# Merging media queries, using SASS and Breakpoint (Respond-To)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, sass, media-queries

Using SASS and Respond-To (Breakpoint) produces a .css file with multiple media queries, not merged.

Not a big deal, but in IE8, using css3-mediaqueries.js, cause IE8 crash. css3-mediaqueries.js add a style tag for every mediaqueries, and IE8 can't get up to 32...

How can I merge all the media queries automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally, multiple media queries is not a big deal thanks to GZIP being used to compress CSS when passed from server to client.

To enable media queries support in IE7 and 8, i've been succesfully using [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).

See this small guide how to combine Respond.js with Selectivizr: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16732064/901944

Comment: "I can just use gzip" is not a good reason to have an unnecessarily large CSS file.  Gzip doesn't help when your cache size is limited, either.

Comment: Ok thanks, work perfectly ! But I'll try to write something later to merge them, and free some space.

Comment: @cimmanon, you say that SASS does not support automatic grouping of media queries, and Eric Meyer [recommends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12824576/901944) to **never** group styles by media queries manually. Then why do you consider the CSS to be **unnecessarily** large?

Comment: I don't believe I said any such thing.  If the OP has so many media queries that it is causing the browser to crash, I can only assume the worst and that they've got more than 1-3 media queries per partial.  Anything more than that is, yes, unnecessary.

Comment: @cimmanon, IE8 does not support media queries. It crashes due to an unhappy polyfill used.

Comment: I only wanted to group mediaqueries on the .css output, not on .sass (having MQ next to elements is definitely easier to maintain). The main problem was the polyfill (css3-mediaqueries.js) not working with more than 32 media queries. But respond-js seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sass does not have this functionality.  Either plan your media queries better so that you only have a few as possible or find a 3rd party application that will merge them for you.