# SASS and media query aggregation

Tags: sass

Using Sass, I have the following mixin:

```
@mixin ss($property, $value, $value-smallscreen) {
  #{$property}: $value;
  @media screen and (max-height: $smallscreen-maxheight) {
    #{$property}: $value-smallscreen;
  }
}

.Header
{
  @include ss('height', $RowHeight, $RowHeight-smallscreen);
  @include ss('font-size', $HeaderFontsize, $HeaderFontsize-smallscreen);
}
```

The ‘problem’ that I have is that this generates two @media statements. That is, it generates the following CSS:

```
.Header {
  height: 41px;
  font-size: 11pt; }
  @media screen and (max-height: 768px) {
    .Header {
      height: 35px; } }
  @media screen and (max-height: 768px) {
    .Header {
      font-size: 9pt; } }
```

What I want to know, is there any way to both:

- Keep the definitions together, to ensure that the styles are added for both big and small screens, and
- Only have one '@media' section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging media queries, using SASS and Breakpoint (Respond-To)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478693/merging-media-queries-using-sass-and-breakpoint-respond-to)

Comment: @cimmanon I don't believe that this is a duplicate, since I know that there are multiple media queries. The answer there, is "don't create multiple". My question is "Is there a way to not create multiple, and not duplicate the definitions in SASS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my current projects requires this approach to the SASS structure, and my solution has been to watch the CSS output using a CSS post-processor like [Pleeease](http://pleeease.io/) to watch the CSS files as SASS/Compass outputs them.

This allows live media query packing among other optimization.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate this kind of post processing phase. I was hoping to avoid it, but maybe it is the best solution.