# Combining SASS mixin output to a variable

Tags: css, sass

I'm using a SASS mixin to wrap my SASS in media queries so I can easily adjust the breakpoints later on.

That works perfectly, however, since I'm calling the mixin several times it results in having a ton of media queries in my compiled CSS. I would like to combine all media queries to one single media query for each breakpoint.

I'm wondering if it is possible to append the output of a mixin to a variable? Or is there any other way to achieve the same result with SASS only?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've been pointed out that this question is a duplication of [Merging media queries, using SASS and Breakpoint (Respond-To)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478693/merging-media-queries-using-sass-and-breakpoint-respond-to) it is, however that question (and answers) date back 2013, there might be new functionality added to SASS in the mean time which might make this possible.

Comment: No, Sass has not changed since 2013 in that regard.

Comment: I found this interesting article about that topic: http://sasscast.tumblr.com/post/38673939456/sass-and-media-queries
You should read, then maybe you leave it be.