# .scss, media quires, @content and bourbon neat

Tags: css, sass, bourbon

I'm using Bourbon Neat but I want the compiled css to not keep repeating the media query for each element but to compile it in order mobile first.

My scss looks something like this

```
    #logo {
        @include span-columns(3);
        @include media($mobile) {
            @include span-columns(2);
          }

    }

    nav {
        @include span-columns(6);
        text-align: center;
        li {
            display: inline-block;
            }
            @include media($mobile) {
                @include span-columns(2);
                text-align: right;
              }
    }

    #social {
        @include span-columns(3);
        text-align: right;
        li {
            display: inline-block;
            }

        @include media($mobile) {
            display:none;
          }

}
```

How can I achieve cleaner organised compiled css?

Here is what I get at the moment:

```
#logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 23.23176%; }
  #logo:last-child {
    margin-right: 0; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #logo {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 7.42297%;
      width: 46.28851%; }
      #logo:last-child {
        margin-right: 0; } }

nav {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 48.82117%;
  text-align: center; }
  nav:last-child {
    margin-right: 0; }
  nav li {
    display: inline-block; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    nav {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 7.42297%;
      width: 46.28851%;
      text-align: right; }
      nav:last-child {
        margin-right: 0; } }

#social {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 23.23176%;
  text-align: right; }
  #social:last-child {
    margin-right: 0; }
  #social li {
    display: inline-block; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #social {
      display: none; } }
```

I have tried using the @content technique by doing this at the top:

```
$mobile: new-breakpoint(max-width 480px 4);

@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == small {
    @include media($mobile) { @content; }
  }
```

And changing the @include to this:

```
#logo {
    @include span-columns(3);
    @include breakpoint(small) {
        @include span-columns(2);
      }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS Placeholder for media query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619493/sass-placeholder-for-media-query)

Comment: Just a note: `css` rules are applied in the order they are in the `css` file. The compiler will maintain this order when translating from `scss` to `css`, because without knowing the `html` code there is no way to figure out if moving rules around would change the style of your document.

Comment: @cimmanon thank you very much for showing me SASS Placeholder for media query? So as I understand it there is no such thing as mobile first css when using .scss? you just have css cascading down until it hits the media query which is duplicated under each element or class/id?

Comment: @t.niese so 'global' or constant styles go after the media query mixin's? but there is no way to not have many duplicate media queries throughout my complied css?

Comment: There's no consolidating media queries in Sass.  That's all there is to it.  If you don't want duplicate media queries in your CSS, then don't write so many media queries.  Sass doesn't care what order you do your stuff, it just compiles to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In order to code mobile-first, you need to make standard styles for mobile devices, and then use media queries to scale your design on bigger screens.
Also, make sure to use the `min-width` tag instead of `max-width`, and introduce layout-specific rules only when you need them.

You can read more about mobile-first here: http://adamkaplan.me/grid/

Example using Bourbon Neat:

```
    ul.navigation-list {
    display:none;
        @include media($large-screen) {
            display:block;
        }
    }
```